# Custom HealthKit HKQuantityType Identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, enums, healthkit

I would like to add new HKQuantityTypeIdentifiers for HealthKit Samples.  I created an enum with the types I was interested in and then I tried to create a property with HKQuantityType.quantityTypeforIdentifier but the property returned nil.

I also tried to define an extension for HKQuantityType for my custom identifiers but that did not work either. See code below. Any ideas?

```
enum DistanceType : String {
    case gpsDistance = "GPSdistance"
    case activityDistance = "activityDistance"
}

let distanceType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(DistanceType.gpsDistance.rawValue)

extension HKQuantityType {
    enum extDistance  {
        case gpsDistance = "GPS"
        case activityDistance = "activityDistance"    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add type identifiers to HealthKit. The framework only supports a predefined set of types.

Answer (score 0):

Extension of HKQuantityType for a readable description.

I have only listed out three here but of course you can add additional descriptions where needed (eg. .dietaryProtein = "Protein")

```
extension HKQuantityType {

var readableDescription: String {
    
    switch self {
    case .quantityType(forIdentifier:  .distanceWalkingRunning)!:
        return "Distance Running + Walking"
        
    case .quantityType(forIdentifier:  .distanceCycling)!:
        return "Distance Cycling"
        
    case .quantityType(forIdentifier:  .distanceSwimming)!:
        return "Distance Swimming"
        
    default:
        print(self.identifier)
        return "Other"
    }
}}
```

Usage:

```
i.quantityType.readableDescription
```